# How to update VS code to the latest version in Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, visual-studio-code

I saw many solutions like 
`wget https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/latest/linux-deb-x64/stable -O /tmp/code_latest_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/code_latest_amd64.deb`
Buts its not too good.
I want to update VS code in Ubuntu in a single command.

Comment: I had already mentioned about that. see my description. That's all answers doesn't meet my expectation.

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/a/905895/760903 or https://askubuntu.com/a/1016764/760903 don't? Read them carefully

Answer (score 5):

It's too simple.

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade code
```

Comment: Moreover, the `--only-upgrade` is likely not necessary.